# Unable To Read local JSON File using spark submit

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am reading JSON file in scala spark using

> val df=spark.read.json(properties.getProperty("jsonFilePath"))

This code works when I run from my IDE(Intellij)
But when I try to execute using spark-submit command, it gives the below message

```
INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: file:///Users/path/to/json/file.json, range: 0-8822, partition values: [empty row]
```

I am not able to process the JSON data due to this. Any idea what could be happening here?

Here is my spark submit command:

```
${SPARK_HOME_DIR}/bin/spark-submit --master local ${SCALA_JAR_LOC}/<JARNAME>.jar
```

I tried providing it as part of spark-submit using --files option as well. Need help

Comment: My JSON is put as a single line in a file in the resources folder of the project structure. There is a properties file to point to that location of json file

Answer (score 0):

`spark.read.json` supports reading data from a filesystem that's supported by Hadoop. If the JSON is part of the jar that contains your jar you can use the `getClass.getResourceAsStream` java API to read the json from the classpath of the job.

To read the JSON file from your classpath

```
def read(file: String): String = {
  val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$file")
  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream)
    .getLines
    .toList
    .mkString(" ")
    .trim
    .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
}
```

Since you want to read that JSON as a dataframe in your code, you might have to convert the String to an RDD and then to a single record dataframe.

```
val inputAsRDD = sparkCtxt.parallelize(List(read("/path/within/resources/folder")))
val df = sparkSession.read.json(inputAsRDD)
```